# Backbone.view options error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, attributes, attr

i've got text toolbar: http://take.ms/V4b1g

This is "backbone.view" function:

```
define([
'View/Popup',
'text!Templates/Toolbar/Edit.tpl'
], function(Popup, _edit){

var Edit = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'svs-cke',
    events:{
        'mousedown':                'mousedown',
        'click .bold':              'toggleBold',
        'click .italic':            'toggleItalic',
        'click .underline':         'toggleUnderline',
        'click .link':              'toggleLink',

        'click .size':              'toggleSize',

        'keypress [name="size"]':   'setSize',

        'keypress [name="link"]':   'setUrl'
    },

    initialize: function(){

    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.append(_.template(_edit).apply(this.options));
        return this.$el;
    },

    mousedown: function(e){
        if(e.target !== this.$el.find('[name="link"]').get(0)){
            //e.preventDefault();
        }
    },

    toggleSize: function(e){
        this.$el.find('[name="size"]').val(this.options.size.attr('class'));
        this.$el.find('[name="size"]').show();
        this.$el.find('[name="size"]').focus();
    },

    setSize: function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(e.currentTarget).val();
            if(url.length > 0){
                this.options.size.attr('class', url);
                this.options.size.trigger('sizeChange');
            }else{
                this.options.size.attr('class', '#');
                this.options.size.trigger('sizeChange');
            }

            $(e.currentTarget).hide();
        }
    },

    toggleBold: function(e){
        document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
        $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('t-active');
    },

    toggleItalic: function(e){
        document.execCommand('italic', false, null);
        $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('t-active');
    },

    toggleUnderline: function(e){
        document.execCommand('underline', false, null);
        $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('t-active');
    },

    toggleLink: function(e){
        if(this.options.nodes.url){
            this.$el.find('[name="link"]').val(this.options.nodes.url);
        }

        this.lastRange = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        this.$el.find('[name="link"]').show();
        this.$el.find('[name="link"]').focus();
    },

    setUrl: function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
            e.preventDefault();
            this.$el.find('[name="link"]').blur();
            window.getSelection().addRange(this.lastRange);
            var url = $(e.currentTarget).val();
            if(url.length > 0){
                document.execCommand('createLink', false, url);
            }else{
                document.execCommand('unlink', false, null);
            }

            $(e.currentTarget).hide();
            this.$el.find('.link').toggleClass('t-active');
        }
    }
});

return Edit;
});
```

when i'm trying to click on this: http://take.ms/X7dpz i've got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined
```

in this line:

```
this.$el.find('[name="size"]').val(this.options.size.attr('class'));
```

what i'm doing wrong in this line? thx!

Comment: you didn't pass size in options )) Please show code where you instantiate you class ( like $var = new Edit() ) - there you should pass some object inside new Edit() construction - it must contain size property

Answer (score 2):

Backbone views used to attach the options passed to the constructor in the view's `this.options` but that stopped a long time ago. From the [Change Log](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog):

> **1.1.0 — Oct. 10, 2013**
>   [...]
>   - Backbone Views no longer automatically attach options passed to the constructor as `this.options` and Backbone Models no longer attach `url` and `urlRoot` options, but you can do it yourself if you prefer.

If you want to use `this.options` in your views, set it up yourself:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    this.options = options;
}
```

or better, use [`_.pick`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) to grab just the keys you're expecting:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    this.options = _(options || { }).pick('option', ...);
}
```

or [`_.defaults`](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults) to fill in default values for your options:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    this.options = _({ }).defaults(options || { }, { /* defaults go here... */ });
}
```

Using `_.pick` or `_.defaults` as above also has the happy side effect of copying the `options` so that you accidentally change something that doesn't belong to you.

Comment: initialize() only gets whitelisted options defined in View.viewOptions list. constructor() still gets non-whitelisted options as an argument, but it is called after initialize().

Comment: @bmadigan Any idea when `viewOptions` was added? I haven't used Backbone for a few years.

Comment: no not sure. The reason for picking only those options is also not clear.